# Time taken to discharge a gas tank from an orifice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gas

I have a pressurized tank with a total volume of 100L filled with nitrogen gas. The tank has an orifice of 20mm which vents out to atmosphere. The initial pressure in the tank = 100Mpa, and final pressure = 1Mpa. Initial temperature is 300K. I need to find the **final temperature** of the gas and also the **time it would take** for the gas to discharge causing the pressure change. Any guidance in solving this problem would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: To get the final temperature in the tank (assuming that it is insulated),, you just require that the entropy per unit mass of the gas remaining in the tank does not change.  To get the time, unfortunately, you need to measure the flow characteristics of the valve.